# CGContextFillRect not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, quartz-graphics

This code appears to do nothing. Build successful, no errors. No rectangle drawn on screen.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIColor *reliantMagenta             = [UIColor colorWithRed:208.0f / 255.0f green:27.0f / 255.0f blue:124.0f / 255.0f alpha:1];

    CALayer *reliantCanvasLayer         = [CALayer layer];

    reliantCanvasLayer.frame            = CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 960);

    [[[self view] layer] addSublayer:reliantCanvasLayer];

    CGContextRef ctx                    = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect leftRect                     = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300);

    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, reliantMagenta.CGColor);

    CGContextFillRect(ctx, leftRect);
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);

}
```

I am just learning Quartz and really thrashing with it. If you want to explain the relationship between UIViews, CALayers, CGLayers, and context that would be a big help too, but not required, just having trouble understanding what is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're starting out with Quartz, then you should start with the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html), which walks through all of this. Your key mistake here is that there is no context available in `viewDidLoad`. Drawing of this kind is generally done in `drawRect:`. Your call to `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` returns `NULL` at this point.

After reading through the Programming Guide, you may have more questions, but that's where you should start to learn about custom drawing.

Comment: And this might help: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html That's about drawing; other chapters of my book answer the OP's other conceptual questions in depth.

Comment: So can I get a context from the CALayer? Or do I need to do a create CALayer with context? Does this mean that not all layers have a context?

Comment: Layers don't have contexts, they have contents, which is a different thing. Contexts are generally used for drawing into views, though they can be used to draw into bitmaps, PDFs, and the like. A context generally is a temporary thing, created just when drawing is required, and then written to the screen. A brand new (empty) context is created the next time you draw. It's not like a permanent canvas that you keep layering thing onto over long periods of time. Read through the Overview of the Quartz 2D PG, and the first part of the "Graphics Contexts" section. The basics are explained there.

Comment: The key to remember is that when drawing is required, you will be handed a fresh, empty context in `drawRect:`. It is your responsibility to draw your entire contents at that point. This is the standard way to perform custom drawing in iOS. There are other approaches (such as CALayer), but this is a very common way. iOS has many techniques for making sure that drawRect: isn't called too often.

Comment: so drawRect wil create a context that I can then draw too.

Comment: correct. In drawRect:, calls to UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() will return a useable context. What you draw there will appear in the view.

Comment: So it looks like drawRect is its own method. Is there no way to get a usable context without adding an additional method? I'm sorry I am still not getting it, even after reading the documentation.

Comment: The point isn't that `drawRect:` is a separate method. `drawRect:` is called by the system at the point in time that drawing is required. You do not draw until drawing is requested. (It is possible to generate a bitmap context, draw into that, and capture the result into an image at any time, but you would still need to actually draw that image in `drawRect:`). Again to be clear: views do not have a persistent context that you draw into. They have a short-lived context created immediately when drawing is required, `drawRect:` fills them in, and then the context is composited and discarded.